# XmlDocument InnerXml adds redundant namespace attributes

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

Using C# XmlDocument object to edit an xml document which includes namespace declarations:

```
<tdl xmlns="http://www.nema.org/1997/C1219TDLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tbd="http://www.example.com/tables/tbd/"
   xmlns:xxx="http://www.example.com/tables/xxx/"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nema.org/1997/C1219TDLSchema C1219TDL.xsd" 
   version="1.0" ></tdl>
```

I then add nodes to the document (setting `InnerXml`) that have tags and attributes that reference these namespaces.

I have 2 problems:

1. If the created tag is in the default namespace, it is written with an empty namespace attribute

   ```
   <packedRecord name="ITEM_RCD" xmlns="">
   ```
2. If it uses a defined namespace, then it includes the namespace attribute:

   ```
   <tbd:text xmlns:tbd="http://www.example.com/tables/tbd/">Ph</tbd:text>
   ```

Since these name spaces are defined in the document, my understanding (based on [MSDN - XmlDocument.InnerXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml(v=vs.110).aspx)) was that InnerXml would strip them out.

How do I get them to be stripped out?

Comment: I never heard of `InnerXml` to change namespaces/prefixes... Do you have any link that confirms/explains "my understanding was that InnerXml would strip them out"?

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This links states "InnerXml removes redundant namespace declarations. As a result, numerous cut and paste operations do not increase the size of your document with redundant namespace declarations"

Comment: What I am doing is creating an app that modifies an existing XML file. It creates new elements (using standard XML functions like CreateElement, SetAttribute, etc). At this point, there are no redundant name space attributes. However, I then use OuterXml to get the raw XML (to allow user to edit raw XML). This adds the namespace attributes (that is OK). After the user completes any edits, I use InnerXml to re-insert the updates. I expect that to undo the namespaces added by OuterXml

Comment: Hmm... `InnerXml` is very confusing method than (granted I should have checked MSDN before commenting). I'd be very concerned with "4....from a document that has no default namespace to a document that does have a default namespace, the new **nodes will pick up the new default namespace**." I'm not sure why that is good idea, but you may want to actually write your own copying code. At very least check out source first - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlElement.cs,498a9416f999795a

Comment: Side note: unless you are writing XML editor to very knowledgeable and friendly users (in sense they'll follow whatever extra rules you ask them too) I'd be try to avoid letting them to edit raw XML. I.e. not everyone can properly encode values in they head, many people have hard time distinguishing between attributes and values, some will be puzzled by whitespace normalization...

Comment: Also consider providing [MCVE] so if someone wants to experiment they don't need to re-write code you already have. (I would just write my own insert method to have complete control of handling of namespaces/ namespace prefixes)